# Need assistance with looping in java

Tags: java, loops

Currently working on some extra problem sets and seem to be stuck with this one. I need to make the following output:

```
    *   *    
    * *    
* * * * * 
  * *     
*   *
```

I've got the cross down but i'm having problems with the middle line and was hoping someone could help me figure it out. Heres my code so far (input is set to 5):

```
public static void drawPlusVersion3(int input){
         if (input % 2 != 0)  {
 for(int c = 0; c < input; c++) {
        for(int r = 0; r < input; r++) {
            if((c == input / 2) || (r == input / 2)) 
                System.out.print("*");
            if ( c == r){
                System.out.print("*");
                }
            else 
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
    }
```

Current output:

```
*   *      
  * *      
*  *  ** *  *  
    *  *   
    *    *
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know *why* your program prints what it prints?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger? That is the place to start and you should do that before posting here so you have a better idea of what's behaving unexpectedly.  It is likely that if you use the debugger one line at a time you'll find your error.  With this type of question, you will save yourself and the rest of us a lot of time if you apply good debugging technique before asking here.

Comment: @immibis i know what the code does but im not sure why those 2 stars are sticking together and ruining the pattern

Comment: @Jim Garrison my debugger isn't telling me anything i already tried it. heres what it looks like:      Listening on 53666
    User program running
    User program finished

Comment: what is `input` ? I mean in your demonstration, how much is `input`

Comment: Your debugger doesn't ever "tell" you anything. You step through the code and examine variables at each step to see what's happening.

Comment: @Nguyen Quang Anh ipnut is just an argument that is stated in the main program. it can be any odd number

Comment: ok so in the example, your `input` is 5 ? That's what I mean, number of line, or anything else

Comment: yes sorry should have been more clear.

Comment: [It's not too late.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37934891/edit)

Comment: @RonLevitzky So, you don't know why your program prints what it prints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < input; j++) {
        if (j == input / 2 || i == input / 2 || i + j == input - 1) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This works however i dont think you need the space after the `*` in `System.out.print("* ");`

Comment: @RonLevitzky It's up to you. Your sample output had spaces, so I included it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
    public static void drawPlusVersion3(int input){
        if (input % 2 != 0)  {
for(int c = 0; c < input; c++) {
       for(int r = input - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
           if((c == input / 2) || (r == input / 2) || c == r) 
               System.out.print("*");
           else 
               System.out.print(" ");
               System.out.print(" ");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
}
   }
```

Comment: This gives the same output just in the opposite direction and the 2 stars are still touching each other for some reason

Comment: it was that simple eh. do you mind explaining why just moving the `c == r` into the `if` statement changed the outcome? still a little confused.

Comment: Because you need to print star at position which c = input/2 or r = input/2 or r=c, that's all @RonLevitzky